# how to remove the print lines in bash into a log file when start a flask app?

Tags: python, flask

I start a flask application in bash like

> python app.py &

But there is a lot of output informations in the bash when the application running, just as

> Running on http://0.0.0.0:9999/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
>   "GET /hash/da9ba7b0369fa343f6cd5797cd9bcc49 HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Is there any ways to remove these output informations into a log file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

> python app.py &>> log.txt

using single '>' character will truncate the previous data in log file each time new output comes but '>>' will append output.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can capture both standard output & error like this (and run in the background):

```
(python app.py 2&>1 >logfile.txt &)
```

If you want to suppress output completely and drop the log:

```
(python app.py 2&>1 >/dev/null &)
```

The parenthesis even suppress the job number `[1] 4456` displayed to show the background process id.